# how to declare an unsigned int in a C program

Tags: c, bit-fields

On this link I came across
http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v2.6.36/include/linux/pci.h#L299
integer declaration
 `unsigned int    is_added:1;`I have made C programs and declared integers in them but in the above I see use of
**:**
What sort of syntax is that?

Comment: It's probably some preprocessor magic happening.

Comment: Why the hell does the above comment have 2 upvotes?

Comment: @OmnipotentEntity and the two upvoters:  it's a bitfield.

Comment: When did magic start working in C?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you have come across a [bit-field](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yszfawxh(VS.80).aspx) :)

Comment: ha ha :) ok by reading rest of the replies I am now able to understand what is the above thing.

Answer (score 3):

It's part of a `struct`, which means that it indicates that the field should only use a certain number of bits instead of an entire byte or more.

Answer (score 3):

This is bit field declaration in an array. The number post ":" denotes number of bits to allocate to this particular field of the structure.

Although you need to be careful with bit-fields as their binary representation is not portable.  That is you are passing binary blobs  between interfaces compiled with different compilers it may not work.

Comment: Ok Now I understand I had completely forgotten such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

This indicates that only one bit of this will be used.

Answer (score 0):

In `struct`s, one can have integer variables that occupy any number of bits between 1 and 31. `is_added` is such a one-bit variable.  One-bit variables are also known as flags.

Comment: where you get the number 31 from? This is misleading. You may use as many as the width of `int`, which is at least 32. You should be a bit cautious about the sign bit, but since here the field is declared `unsigned int` it can hold at least 32 bit without pain.

Comment: @Jens: The width of an int can be as small as 16 bits in C99.